# How can I pass a variable into a Mailchimp function as a parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I feel this is a very basic question so I do apologise in advance, I have spent some hours before deciding to ask this.

In short, I am using the MailChimp API to archive/delete a user.

```
public function archiveClient(Request $request){

        $client_email = md5(strtolower($request->client_email));

        $mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
        $mailchimp->setConfig([
            'apiKey' => config('services.mailchimp.key'),
            'server' => 'us14'
        ]);

        $mailchimp->lists->deleteListMember("list_id", "<?php $client_email ?>");
        
    }
```

`List_id` works just fine, I have used it in other functions to add subscribers. I changed it back to `list_id` for privacy. However the `subscriber_hash` parameter requires an MD5 hash of the user's email in lowercase and this is where the problem comes in. I've tried various ways but I still come to the same error:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
>
> Client error: DELETE
> https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/list_id/members/%3C%3Fphp%20d076a26e78f7e9935a3af1a8f5124b98%20%3F%3E
> resulted in a 404 Not Found response:
> {"type":"https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/","title":"Resource
> Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The (truncated...)

The targeted email address is there on Mailchimp and comes through correctly as a string in the `$request->client_email`, the issue is with the hash somehow. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Should it not just be: `$mailchimp->lists->deleteListMember("list_id", $client_email);`?

Comment: You're passing the string "<?php $client_email ?>" to the delete function. You want to juse pass `$client_email` there.

Comment: ...to add to my previous comment: Note that within the client error, the `%3C%3Fphp%20d076a26e78f7e9935a3af1a8f5124b98%20%3F%3E` shows `%3C` is `<`, the `%3F` is the `?`, ... then `php`, the `%20` is a space, _then_ the hash, and closing with another space, ?, and then `%3E` which is `>`.

Comment: Changing the parameters to ("list_id", $client_email); delivers a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above suggestions by Paul T and Greg Schmidt are correct!

Parameters should be set to ("list_id", $client_email)

After this fix I received a 405 error which was truncated. I therefore used the following to find the precise error:

```
try {
            $mailchimp->lists->deleteListMember("list_id", $client_email);
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $ex) {
            return $ex->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
        }
```

The cause was that I used a contact that was 'cleaned'. After testing on a 'subscribed' member it worked just fine.